# Pair of Cartesian Cordinates for a line that is tangent to two surfaces.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tangent-line

Find a pair of linear cartesian equations for the line which is tangent to both the surfaces (a) $x^2 +y^2 + 2z^2 = 4 $ and (b) $z=e^{(x-y)}$ at point $(1,1,1)$.

My steps:

(1) find the tangent plane vector at (1,1,1) for each equation

(a) $\langle 2x-2,2y-2,4z-4\rangle$

(b) $\langle\,x-1,y-1,z-1\rangle$

(2) I guess I must now use the cross product of the two vectors above to find the vector that lies on both lines? I am a little confused as to where to go from here, would apreciate any help

Comment: Are you expected to find a parametric equation for the line, rather than an implicit one? If the latter, then once you have equations for the two tangent planes, you’re done.

Comment: expected to find an implicit one! so having trouble post cross product haha

Comment: You have the normals to the two tangent planes, but you’ve got a little more work to do to find their equations.

Comment: this was the answer but not set as one but wanted to say thank you, makes sense now

Comment: Since you’ve already accepted another answer, I won’t bother writing my comment up as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing fine. You've found the vectors perpendicular to the two surfaces at any point $(x,y,z)$. Now at $P = (1,1,1)$, you can actually find numerical values for those "normal vectors"; the first is 
$$
n_1 = \pmatrix{2x, 2y, 4z} = \pmatrix{2, 2, 4}
$$
You can compute the second.

The cross product $n_1 \times n_2$, and this will be the direction along a line that lies in both planes (because it's perpendicular to both normal-vectors). Let's suppose that cross product is $v = (a, b, c)$. 
Then your line passes through $(1,1,1)$ in direction $(a, b, c)$. Can you find the equation for this line?

Hint: I suggest finding a *parametric* equation for the line rather than an *implicit* one.

Comment: this wasnot the answer, the tangent planes were enough to express a set of equations tangent to the surfaces at (1,1,1) but thank you for the help, because your answer taught me a few things regardless